# Solve Huber's M-Estimation using quadratic programming

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-programming

The Huber's M-estimate is to solve the problem

$$\underset{\mathbf x}{\rm{minimize}} \rho(\mathbf b-\mathbf A\mathbf x) + \alpha|\mathbf x|$$
where
$$ \rho(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{c}\frac{t^2}{2\gamma}\quad\;\;\;\;\; \text{if } |t|<\gamma\\ |t|-\frac{\gamma}{2}\quad \text{if } |t|\geq \gamma\end{array}\right.$$

First, we ignore the term $\alpha |\mathbf x|$ in the objective function.

Let $\mathbf r=\mathbf b-\mathbf A\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf p$ contain elements of $|\mathbf r|$ which are larger than $\gamma$, otherwise the elements are set to 0. On the other hand, let $\mathbf q$ contain elements of $|\mathbf r|$ which are smaller than $\gamma$, otherwise the elements are set to 0. Then, $|\mathbf r| = \mathbf p + \mathbf q$. Then, we have:
$$|\mathbf b-\mathbf A\mathbf x| = |\mathbf r| = \mathbf p + \mathbf q$$
It implies:
$$-\mathbf p - \mathbf q \leq \mathbf b-\mathbf A\mathbf x \leq \mathbf p + \mathbf q$$
The objective function becomes:
$$\frac{1}{2\gamma}\mathbf p^T\mathbf p + \mathbf e^T(\mathbf q-\frac{\gamma}{2}\mathbf e)$$
where
$$\mathbf 0 \leq \mathbf p \leq \gamma\mathbf e$$
$$\mathbf q \geq \gamma\mathbf e \geq \mathbf 0$$

As some of the elements of $\mathbf q$ equal 0, the second constraint should be $$\mathbf q \geq \mathbf 0$$

Then the problem becomes

$$\underset{\mathbf x, \mathbf p, \mathbf q}{\rm{minimize}} \frac{1}{2\gamma}\mathbf p^T\mathbf p + \mathbf e^T(\mathbf q-\frac{\gamma}{2}\mathbf e)$$
subject to
$$-\mathbf p - \mathbf q \leq \mathbf b-\mathbf A\mathbf x \leq \mathbf p + \mathbf q$$
$$\mathbf 0 \leq \mathbf p \leq \gamma\mathbf e$$
$$\mathbf q \geq 0$$

Now, we include the term $\alpha|\mathbf x|$ in the objective function. Express $\mathbf x = \mathbf x^+ - \mathbf x^- $ where $\mathbf x^+$ and $\mathbf x^-$ contain non-negative and negative elements (positive in $\mathbf x^-$) of $\mathbf x$, respectively. For example, $\mathbf x =[-2, 3, 5, -4]$, then $\mathbf x^+ = [0, 3, 5, 0]$ and $\mathbf x^-=[2, 0, 0, 4]$

Then, we have:
$$\underset{\mathbf x^+, \mathbf x^-, \mathbf p, \mathbf q}{\rm{minimize}} \frac{1}{2\gamma}\mathbf p^T\mathbf p + \mathbf e^T(\mathbf q-\frac{\gamma}{2}\mathbf e) + \alpha(\mathbf x^+ +\mathbf x^-)$$
subject to
$$-\mathbf p - \mathbf q \leq \mathbf b-[\mathbf A\;\;-\mathbf A]\left[\begin{array}{c}\mathbf x^+ \\ \mathbf x^-\end{array}\right] \leq \mathbf p + \mathbf q$$
$$\mathbf 0 \leq \mathbf p \leq \gamma\mathbf e$$
$$\mathbf q \geq 0$$
$$\mathbf x^+ \geq 0$$
$$\mathbf x^- \geq 0$$